# Which permissions does an Android launcher need to run shortcuts

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-launcher, android-shortcut

I am writing an Android launcher that does not support widgets, but it does support shortcuts. One of the shortcuts provided by AOSP is Direct dial, and my launcher needs the android.permission.CALL_PHONE permission for that. My question is, are there any other permissions that I need to add, to allow all possible shortcuts, even those provided by third party apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer, as I couldn't find this explicitly stated anywhere, but it seems that only phone call shortcuts require a permission, so the CALL_PHONE permission is the only one you need, to launch shortcuts.

AOSP launcher only checks for the CALL_PHONE permission. Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/src/com/android/launcher3/Launcher.java#1630

I haven't been able to find any other types of shortcuts that require permissions.

Answer (score 0):

FOR NOUGAT SHORTCUTS ( API LEVEL 25+ )

There is not standard permission to add/launch shortcuts. If target api level of your app is 25+, you can use ShortcutManager or static shortcut via .xml meta-data.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

FOR LEGACY SHORTCUTS ( BELOW API LEVEL 25 )

If you want to install&use Legacy shortcuts without user interaction, you need to declare INSTALL SHORTCUT permission.

Legacy shortcuts use Intent Action:

Create shortcut for Launcher: "android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"

Install shortcut on Launcher: "com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"

Required permission on AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

You can find more resources when you search for intent actions above.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough that I'm creating a launcher. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know this in advance. Some apps just assume that the caller of their shortcuts have some permissions (e.g. some system launcher shortcuts often only work in the system launcher itself, as they sometimes require some self defined permission).

In general, any app that offers shortcuts, *should* run the code in itself instead of the calling app to be sure the required permissions are present, but apparently this is not the case in some apps (especially in launchers e.g.).

I face this problem in an app of mine every now and then as well and catch the exception and tell the user, that the selected shortcut does not support other apps and is implemented in a wrong way.

**Example - shortcut to call someone that works and that does not work**

E.g. think about a third party app that offers a direct call shortcut. It can handle this in 2 way:

**wrong way**

It can return an intent like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
...
```

This intent can ONLY be run by an app that has the action call permission

**correct way**

The app knows, that the caller may not have the call phone permission, so it does not return the direct phone call intent directly, but a custom one that it handles itself like e.g.

```
Intent.ShortcutIconResource icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.mipmap.icon);
Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, MyPhoneCallActivity.class);
launchIntent.putExtra("number", number);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(pause != null ? (pause ? R.string.shortcut_pause : R.string.shortcut_resume) : R.string.shortcut_toggle_pause_resume));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
```

If the caller executes the shortcut, the `MyPhoneCallActivity` will be started - this runs inside the app itself and has all permissions of the shortcut provider. This activity then can simply execute the `Intent.ACTION_CALL` intent itself and finishes itself afterwards. This way, the calling app does not need any special permissions. The workaround via an activity is one solution for this problem that works.